# CustomAlertDialog doesn't finish its process after deleting a record of databse

Tags: java, android

I am using my CustomAlertDialog in order to delete a record from database, when I delete one successfully and I attempt to insert a new row into database, the AlertDialog appears again notwithstanding I didn't even call it and when I click the delete button it deletes one record until all the records are deleted and app crashes.

I call it on my AdapterClass =>

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        E04Object obj = object.get(getAdapterPosition()) ;

        id = obj.getId() ;

 if (view == deleteBtn) {

            int position = id ;

            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {

                activityReference.ShowDialog(position);

            }

            clicked = false ;

            } }
```

and I initialize it in my FragmentClass =>

```
@Override
public void ShowDialog(int position) {



    DialogObject dialogObject = new DialogObject() ;
    CustomDialogView customDialogView = new CustomDialogView(getActivity() , dialogObject) ;

    dialogObject.setListener(new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositive() {

            dbConnector.get().execSQL(
                    
                        " DELETE FROM " + db.Tables.MYDB + " WHERE " + db.MYDB.ID + " = " + position );

            customDialogView.hide();

            list.remove(MyAdapter.cardId) ;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


        @Override
        public void onNegative() {
            customDialogView.hide();
        }
    });

    customDialogView.setCancelable(true);
    customDialogView.show();

}
```

Comment: use view.getId() == R.id.deleteBtn( btn id)

Comment: @D_K what was the difference? didn't work out.

Comment: use customDialogView.dismiss(); instead of customDialogView.hide();

Comment: @D_K this one really worked, weird but thank you very much.

Comment: if it helpful please upvote it

Comment: @D_K you can publish it as an answer if you like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   @Override
public void ShowDialog(int position) {



DialogObject dialogObject = new DialogObject() ;
CustomDialogView customDialogView = new CustomDialogView(getActivity() , dialogObject) ;

dialogObject.setListener(new DialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPositive() {

        dbConnector.get().execSQL(
                
                    " DELETE FROM " + db.Tables.MYDB + " WHERE " + db.MYDB.ID + " = " + position );

        customDialogView.dismiss();

        list.remove(MyAdapter.cardId) ;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }


    @Override
    public void onNegative() {
        customDialogView.dismiss();
    }
});

customDialogView.setCancelable(true);
customDialogView.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
customDialogView.hide();
```

replace code with this

```
customDialogView.dismiss();
```